# Change indentation depth when using spaces in lstlisting

Tags: listings, indentation

I have an `lstlisting` that renders some lines of code. The code is indented by four spaces per indent. Is there any setting to change the indentation to only two spaces? I know that there is `tabsize` but that is obviously for tabs and I would like to avoid changing the code itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems easier to use your editor to perform a search-and-replace, since you probably don't have consecutive spaces anywhere else in your code. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach is to use the `literate` key to replace each occurence of two consecutives spaces by one space.

**Caveats**: this approach will

- perform such replacements "within" lines of code also (though not in string literals),
- interfere with the `autogobble` option (offered by the `lstautogobble` package), which is used to remove leading spaces in a listing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% code available at http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html
\begin{filecontents*}{samplecode.py} 
class MyClass:
    """A simple example     class"""
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
\end{filecontents*}

\lstdefinestyle{Python2}
{
    language=Python,
    literate = *{\ \ }{\ }1, %replaces each occurence of two consecutive spaces by one
}

\begin{document}
Indent = 4 spaces (as in the original listing)
\lstinputlisting[language=Python,frame=single]{samplecode.py}
Indent = 2 spaces
\lstinputlisting[style=Python2,frame=single]{samplecode.py}
\end{document}
```